# Integrate $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{a - bx^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've been toiling for hours trying to answer this one:

> Find $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{a - bx^2}}\,dx$

It's from Silvanus Thompson's 'Calculus Made Easy' (apparently not easy enough for me!).

The answer given is $\frac {1}{\sqrt{a}}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a-bx^2}}{x\sqrt{a}}\right)$

I've attempted the question by letting $x=\sqrt{\frac ab}\sin(u)$, which I *think* is on the right track as I end up with the $\frac1{\sqrt a}$ term in my answer, but nothing else falls into place in terms of the given answer.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Andrew

Comment: Show us your try, and maybe we can say something about it

Comment: Maybe you have got the correct answer but you need to simplify it in order to get to the answer key. But another approach that will give the answer your book has given would be substituting $u=a-bx^2$ then you get $\int\frac{1}{u^{\frac{1}{2}}(u-a)}du$. Then you will get to do another substitution and you will get an easy integral

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Your method seems to work, provided anyway that $a, b > 0$: The substitution $x = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \sin \theta$, $dx = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \cos \theta \,d\theta$ transforms the integral to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int \csc \theta \,d\theta .$$

Another option avoids trigonometric functions altogether: Rewrite the integral as
$$\int \frac{x \,dx}{x^2 \sqrt{a - b x^2}} .$$

What substitution does this form of the integrand suggest?

> **Additional hint** Consider the substitution $u^2 = a - b x^2$, $du = -2 b x \,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=\sqrt{\frac ab }\frac1t$ to get

$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a - bx^2}}=-\frac1{\sqrt a}\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}= - \frac1{\sqrt a}\cosh^{-1}t=- \frac1{\sqrt a}\ln\left(t+\sqrt{t^2-1}\right)
$$

which is equal to $\frac {1}{\sqrt{a}}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a-bx^2}}{x\sqrt{a}}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{a-bx^2}}=\int\dfrac{bx\ dx}{bx^2\sqrt{a-bx^2}}$$

Let $\sqrt{a-bx^2}=u\implies du=\dfrac{{-bx}}{\sqrt{a-bx^2}}$  and $bx^2=a-u^2$

More generally for $$\int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{a-bx^n}}=\int\dfrac{bx^{n-1}\ dx}{bx^n\sqrt{a-bx^n}}$$

set $\sqrt{a-bx^n}=y$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a-bx^2}}$$
Let $x=\sqrt\frac{a}{b}\sin t$, then
$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{a/b} \cos t!dt}{\sqrt{a/b} \sin t \sqrt{a} \cos t}.$$
$$\implies I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int \csc t dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int \csc t \frac{\csc t+\cot t}{\csc t+ \cot t}dt.$$
Let $\csc t+ \cot t=u$
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int \frac{-du}{u}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{a}}\ln(\csc t+\cot t)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}ln\frac{1-\sqrt{1-c^2x^2}}{cx}+C,c=\sqrt{b/a}$$